# Error Message after attempted .sql import

Tags: templates, joomla, phpmyadmin, importerror, mysqlimport

I use Joomla and I recently installed a new Template.
To make the demo-content of said Template work, I need to import a .sql file into my database using phpMyAdmin.
However, after trying to import the file I get this error message:

SQL-Befehl *[SQL-Order]*:

```
--
-- Datenbank *[database]*: `j17_jp_investment`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Tabellenstruktur *[table structure]* für Tabelle *[table, sheet]* `jos_assets`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `jos_assets` ;
```

MySQL meldet *[reports]*: Dokumentation *[documentation]*

```
#1046 - No database selected
```

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue with a template i just bought!
Add the MySQL sentense: USE jml_d52ka2dc1f; where jml_d52ka2dc1f; is your database name.

Your dump.sql file should looks like this:

```
USE jml_d52ka2dc1f;

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `jml_assets`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jml_assets` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Primary Key',
`parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set parent.',
`lft` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set lft.',
`rgt` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set rgt.',
`level` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The cached level in the nested tree.',
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The unique name for the asset.\n',
`title` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The descriptive title for the asset.',
`rules` varchar(5120) NOT NULL COMMENT 'JSON encoded access control.',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `idx_asset_name` (`name`),
 KEY `idx_lft_rgt` (`lft`,`rgt`),
 KEY `idx_parent_id` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=43 ;
```

:) Enjoy!

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a database called "j17_jp_investment"?

Otherwise remove that line from the .sql file, go to phpmyadmin, choose the database that joomla is using then go to the import tab and try importing.

Answer (score 0):

The same error was showing up for me. I was trying to import my client's mySQL database to my WAMP server.

I just added these two words at the beginning of my SQL queries:

`USE [database_name]`

However, before doing so, I made sure that I created a database with the exact same name that I'm using in the code above.